# Why does Texstudio installation require texlive packages when texlive is already installed from the mirror?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, latex, texstudio

I have TexLive already installed in my system. I installed it using the `install-tl.zip` as detailed on their [website](https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html).
[image]

Now I'm trying to install TexStudio via the PPA as detailed [HERE](https://linuxhint.com/install-texstudio-latex-editor-linux/). However, when I'm doing the process, it seems that TexStudio is installing `apt` packages for texlive as well.

[image]

Is there any way to avoid this double installation of TexStudio?

I'm using

> Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64

> Kernel: 5.13.0-52-generic

Comment: Well, obviously you didn't install the .deb packages so apt doesn't know texlive is installed. When I faced this problem over a decade ago, I followed the instructions [here](https://texblog.net/latex-archive/uncategorized/kile-texlive-2008-equivs/) to create a dummy .deb package to satisfy the dependencies for apt. Those instructions are very old, however, and I can't test them as I'm no longer using Ubuntu or other debian based distro. But maybe it'll put you on the right track.

Comment: Installation instructions on upstream websites are generally for people running systems that don't have packaged versions.  and, just as significantly, upstream devs generally don't bother to integrate their software into the actual system it's running on.  your best option is to remove the manually installed version of TeXLive and install the packaged version.

Comment: Also, [please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.